# How to specify what dictionaries should be used by click and press on trackpad?

Tags: macos, trackpad

When I hover on some word and force touch on it then some popup appears and there is the meaning of the selected word. Here is this popup:

[image]

How I can specify what dictionaries should be used by this tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Dictionary.app from the Applications folder, choose Dictionary → Preferences and select and reorder the dictionaries as you desire.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I think I am really close. Is it possible to add may be google translator to this list? I am not native english and I highly prefer to 
try to understand the meaning of the word by reading the explanation on english and if I can't then I will read english-russian translation. Is it possible?

Comment: @Sharikov Unfortunately not, there's no Google Translate.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much. You answered the question perfectly. Ty!